# Find element where doesn't contains a specific class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have two objects on the page with same html. Only one of the element's parent tag doesn't have same class name. When I try using not(contains()) it still shows both elements

below is the xpath I tried and still it is detecting both buttons and always clicking on the second button.

> //div[contains(@class,"jss") and
> not(contains(@class,"canvas-image-export"))]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]

below is the code for first button named Connected where I am interested to get

```
<div class="jss203">
   <div class="MuiTabs-root jss244">
      <div class="MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed" style="overflow: hidden;">
         <div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer" role="tablist">
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary Mui-selected" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Overview</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Data Sources</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
            <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Connected</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

below is the code for second button named Connected which I should not click on

```
<div class="jss197 canvas-image-export">
   <span class="" data-testid="componentContainer">
      <div class="MuiTabs-root jss244">
         <div class="MuiTabs-scroller MuiTabs-fixed" style="overflow: hidden;">
            <div class="MuiTabs-flexContainer" role="tablist">
               <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary Mui-selected" tabindex="0" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="true"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Overview</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
               <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Data Sources</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
               <button class="MuiButtonBase-root MuiTab-root MuiTab-textColorPrimary" tabindex="-1" type="button" role="tab" aria-selected="false"><span class="MuiTab-wrapper">Connected</span><span class="MuiTouchRipple-root"></span></button>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </span>
</div>
```

TIA

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is that you are looking on the upper parent node `<div class="jss197 canvas-image-export">` vs `<div class="jss203">` while there is another element there `<div class="MuiTabs-root jss244">` or `<div class="MuiTabs-root jss244">` and it is also matching your XPath `//div[contains(@class,"jss") and not(contains(@class,"canvas-image-export"))]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]`.
So, to make your XPath work you need to add one more detail: not contains `MuiTabs-root` class, as following:

```
//div[contains(@class,"jss") and not(contains(@class,"canvas-image-export")) and not(contains(@class,"MuiTabs-root"))]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]
```

Comment: Correct. I would suggest not to repeat the predicate on class, but do it like this:
`//div[@class[contains(.,'jss') and not(contains(.,'MuiTabs-root')) and not(contains(.,'canvas-image-export'))]]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]`

Comment: Thanks @SiebeJongebloed. But why is this approach better?

Comment: You reusing @class. it is redundant.

Comment: But this makes expression more precise. We are looking for `class` attribute to have or not to have some value, not **any** attribute to have that value.

Comment: Take a better look at the XPath, . It is using the predicate on the class-attribute. Not any attribute. The `.` is referring to the @class-attribute

Comment: I think you didn't understand me correctly. I said: with my expression we make it more precise to look for `jss` value in `class` attribute only. Not in `id` or `data-test-id` or any other attribute. The same about `canvas-image-export` and `MuiTabs-root` values. These values should not present in `class` attribute only while it will not cover cases where these values can be in text or any other attribute.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248516/discussion-between-siebe-jongebloed-and-prophet).

Comment: Hi there, I tried all of these solutions listed by you all and still its identifying both elements. But luckily I was able to fix the issue. Later I noticed that there is one more parent node that is unique to both elements and I used that at the start of the xpath and that fixed.

Comment: Well, That means you gave us not full details about the situation. That's why it is always preferable to give a URL to page you working on or the entire XML of it.

Answer (score 1):

To get only first div buttons, you can exclude the `span` tag for the second element. Using following `xpath` you can get that.

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'jss')][not(span[@data-testid='componentContainer'])]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]
```

Or

```
//div[starts-with(@class,'jss')][not(span)]//button[contains(.,'Connected')]
```